# DbUnit @DataSet with JUnit @Before

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

colleagues!

Using DbUnit with JUnit I am currently trying to make data set provided by [@DataSet](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/dbunit/annotation/DataSet.html) annotation to be accessible in initialization method marked with [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) - and it looks like it simply do not work - is there some trick I need to use, or it is not possible at all - or instead it should work out-of-the-box and I simply should search for bug in my implementation?

Comment: Can you post some (cut down) code please?

Comment: Does your test class extend UnitilsJUnit3/UnitilsJUnit4?